# Change activity

Tags: android, button, android-activity, android-button

Is it possible if I have 5 (or more buttons) to change activity when all of then are pressed. Like when last button is pressed my app should change activity. And it shouldn't matter what button of those five is pressed last.

Any ideas? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, create an array of booleans for each button:

```
boolean[] pressedButtons = new boolean[5];
```

In each of the listeners, when the button is pressed set the appropriate cell in the array to true, and then call such a method (abstract implementation):

```
private void startActivityIfReady() {
    boolean ready = true;
    for (boolean b : pressedButtons)
        ready = ready && b;
    if (ready) {
        // start your activity
    }
}
```

Comment: So you mean there is this 5 times  boolean[] pressedButtons = new boolean[5]; ? Like boolean[] pressedButtons = new boolean[1]; boolean[] pressedButtons = new boolean[2]; etc.. Or all five buttons are in same? And still I can make every button visibility gone after pressing? :)

Comment: I mean one array for all of them (that's why it's `new boolean[5]`) and yes, you can hide each of the buttons after the press if that's what you want.